# Nav bar disappears in browsers when using css position: fixed;

Tags: css, reactjs

The nav bar disappears in browsers when using CSS `position: fixed;`

Other solutions haven't worked for me. I am using React.js for my project.

[My issue in pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuuEZ.jpg)

I've tried playing with the z-index, but that doesn't fix the problem.

nav.css

```
nav {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    width: max-content;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.7rem 1.7rem;
    z-index: 2;
    position: fixed;
/*Note: when removing 'position: fixed'; the nav bar is present. I want the nav bar to be fixed when I scroll down the page */
      
}
```

Header.jsx

```
import './App.css';
import Nav from './components/nav/Nav';

const App = () => {
  return (
<>
  <Header />
  <Nav />
  <About />
  <Experience />
  <Services />
  <Portfolio />
  <Testimonials />
  <Footer />
  <Contact />
  
</>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Nav.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import './nav.css'
import {AiOutlineHome} from 'react-icons/ai'
import {FiUser} from 'react-icons/fi'
import {BiBookBookmark} from 'react-icons/bi'
import {RiServiceLine} from 'react-icons/ri'
import {TbMessage2} from 'react-icons/tb'

export const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <nav>
    <a href="#"><AiOutlineHome/></a>
    <a href="#about"><FiUser/></a>
    <a href="#experience"><BiBookBookmark/></a>
    <a href="#services"><RiServiceLine/></a>
    <a href="#contact"><TbMessage2/></a>
    </nav>
  )
}
export default Nav
```

Comment: Nick Vu's answer worked! Thank you so much. 
First post on Stackoverflow and I am very grateful for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `position: relative;` and `min-height: 100vh;` to `body`. If you want to make it stick at the bottom, you also need to have `bottom: 0;` on `nav`.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

nav {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: max-content;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.7rem 1.7rem;
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>Your header elements</div>
<nav>
  <a>item 1</a>
  <a>item 2</a>
  <a>item 3</a>
</nav>
```